# how to append data to a file

Tags: c#, filestream

I have this code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(name_loc_ficheiro,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    sw.Write(byteArray,(int)total_bytes_received,(int)byteArray.Length);
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Are you having problems, using the current method?

Comment: Yes. The sw.write is expecting a string as the first parameter.

I do not want to appent text but a byte array. Will that work?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the duplicate..